# How to setup clusures inside function parameter closure?

Tags: ios, swift

What I want to achieve:

```
func test() {
  MyClass().setup {
   $0.testClosure = {
     print("1 closure called")
   }

   $0.test2Closure = {
     print("2 closure called ")
   }
  }
}
```

here is my try but i'm getting error: **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**
I'm just wonder if something like this is even possible?

```
class MyClass {
var testClosure: (() -> Void)
var test2Closure: (() -> Void)

func setup(_ setup: ((_ controller: MyClass) -> Void)) {
  setup(self)
}
```

Comment: Use different names for your parameter and function

Comment: Ok, looks like this was some xcode issue. Code above works.

Answer (score 0):

That code seems convoluted. Why have a setup instance method that takes another instance of your class as a parameter, and then call it with self? It's confusing and odd.

how about this as a much cleaner setup?

```
class MyClass {
    typealias AClosure =  (() -> Void)
    var testClosure: AClosure?
    var test2Closure: AClosure?
    
    // Use this initializer if you want to assign the closures later
    init() {
    }
    
    // Use this intializer to provide the closures when you create an instance.
    init(testClosure: @escaping AClosure, test2Closure: @escaping AClosure) {
        self.testClosure = testClosure
        self.test2Closure = test2Closure
    }
}

func test() {
    let myClass = MyClass(
        testClosure: {
            print("1 closure called")
            
        },
        test2Closure: {
            print("2 closure called")
        }
    )
    myClass.testClosure?()
    myClass.test2Closure?()
}

test()
```

Comment: I wanted it to look like snapKit constraints setup. Setting it up inside init may make init huge if you have multiple closures. Also func setup can be useful for example for additional setup parameters.